# Trim a string using a string from a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, trim

I have a batch the would display usage if your parameter is invalid.

For ex.

```
   Running "sample.bat update fuh"

   :usageactions
   set actions=%*
   set toremove=update
   set todisplay=%actions:%toremove% =%
   echo Error: Invalid Arguments - '%todisplay%'.
   echo Type sample.bat %toremove% -h for usage.
```

Expected Output:

```
  Error: Invalid Arguments - 'fuh'.
  Type sample.bat update -h for usage
```

But my output is:

```
  Error: Invalid Arguments - 'update'.
  Type sample.bat update -h for usage
```

How to achived it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

(By the way, please modify the question if its so confusing.)

Comment: Does the program support only one parameter or multiple parameters?

Comment: To parameters but the second parameter should be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to expand an expression more than once in a line, but the parser can't guess which percents are pairs.

```
set todisplay=%actions:%toremove% =%
```

You could use here delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set toDisplay=!actions:%toRemove% =!
```

First %toRemove% will be expanded and then the line looks like

```
set toDisplay=!actions:update =!
```

and then the exclamation expression will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I have found a solution to my problem, doh. Anyways, here's the solution.

```
:usageactions
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set actions=%*
set toremove=update
set todisplay=!actions:%toremove% =!
echo Error: Invalid Arguments - '%todisplay%'.
echo Type sample.bat %toremove% -h for usage.
endlocal
```

This will display.

```
Error: Invalid Arguments - 'fuh'.
Type sample.bat update -h for usage
```